# replace text or value in same column in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

how to replace value or text in same column in oracle sql?

If I add rows in column actual_year for plant 1234, it is equal to value in the row for plant 1235. Similarly if I add rows in column actual_year for plant 9876, it is equal to value in the row for plant 5432. Now, I want to replace plant 1234 by 1235 and 9876 by 5432. There are many cases like these in my table. Apologies for adding image instead of a table. But I dont know how to add a table here.

[image]

Comment: When editing, simply write the table data in proper columns. Highlight and click `{}`. (You can also read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.)

Comment: Your table is not normalized. If you normalize it, this will not be a problem anymore.

Comment: Please clarify the question for someone to be able to help you. I don't know what do you want to do. Where in your table is column ACTUAL_YEAR (there 5 of them ACTUAL_YE....), what exactly is "If I add rows in column actaul_year for plant 1234, it is equal to value in the row for plant 1235". If it means inserting the row that has same value in column ACTUAL_YEAR for both plants - what do you want to do next, what have you tryed so far and what is the expected result??? Btw. I don't see such a row in your table within any of those ACTUAL_YE.... columns. Please provide something more...

Comment: It is not clear how these other rows to be updated are related to the first one. The numbers for plant 9876 and 5432 seem to very arbitrary. What does "if I add rows in column actual_year" mean? You cannot add a row in a column.